# Add Bootstrap 4 tooltip to dynamic button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I want to add a tooltip to a button which could change after the page is loaded.

For example. I use a button like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-link">Button active</a>
```

Now it could be possible, that the button gets disabled and looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-link disabled">Button disabled</a>
```

I know want to add a tooltip with JS to the disabled button.

I tried this code:

```
$('.btn-link.disabled').tooltip({
    title: '<div class="text-left">Please select color first</div>',
    html: true,
});
```

That doesn't work. I think because the class `disabled` is new and the script for the tooltip couldn't find it when the page loads.
Is there a way to "reload" the function?

Comment: it is not possible to properly control tooltips for disabled elements, [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/)

Comment: Elements with the disabled attribute aren’t interactive, meaning users cannot focus, hover, or click them to trigger a tooltip (or popover). As a workaround, you’ll want to trigger the tooltip from a wrapper <div> or <span>, ideally made keyboard-focusable using tabindex="0", and override the pointer-events on the disabled element.plz see the official documentation Disabled elements section https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Comment: I understand, but the button is not really disabled. it's just a class name

Comment: The class applies `pointer-events: none;` to the element

Comment: hm, there is no `pointer-events: none;` in my class!?

Comment: Are you not using bootstrap? If you are and didn't explicitly override those styles for the `disabled` class then there is.

Comment: I can't find it when I inspect the button. but i trust you ;) Couldn't I overwrite the `pointer-events `? There is no way to add an extra wrapper around the button.

Comment: Yes there is that's what bootstrap recommends:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#disabled-elements

Comment: yes, I understand that, but I have no way to add a wrapper around the button like they suggest.

Comment: Sure you can.. Find my answer below for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do what you are asking. You can update it to your specific use case but this should get you started.

```js
$('.btn-link.disabled').wrap('<span class="d-inline-block" tabindex="0" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Please select color first"></span>');
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn btn-link">Button active</a>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-link disabled">Button disabled</a>



<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: OK, thanks! But the problem is still, that the `disabled` class isn't present if I load the page. So the script doesn't add the tooltip if the class adds later

Comment: @Cray I'm not sure what event adds the disabled class so to help you with that I would need more information. You'll need to insert this inside the code block (from an event I presume) that adds the class.

Comment: Well you ought to add the wrapper on page load and then add the tooltip and take it away on the button becoming or ceasing to be disabled.